# The $H^1$ of a smooth curve and its (generalized) Jacobian variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $\geq 1$ over a number field $k$ with a $k$-rational divisor of degree $1$ inducing the embedding $C \hookrightarrow J$, where $J$ is the Jacobian variety of $C$. I know that $J$ corresponds to the divisor classes of degree zero of $\bar{C} := C \times_k \bar{k}$ and so we have the identification $J \cong \mathrm{Pic}^0(\bar{C})$.

**Question 1.** In the proof of Lemma 2.4 of [this](https://www.math.canterbury.ac.nz/%7Eb.creutz/Papers/Brd_curves.pdf) paper, it is given that the map
$$H^1(k,\mathrm{Pic}^0(\bar{J})) \rightarrow H^1(k,\mathrm{Pic}^0(\bar{C}))$$
of (etale) cohomology groups is an isomorphism. Why is this the case? Do we actually have $\mathrm{Pic}^0(\bar{J}) \cong \mathrm{Pic}^0(\bar{C})$?

By the following commutative diagram, it follows from the isomorphism of the bottom map that $H^1(k,\mathrm{Pic}(\bar{J})) \rightarrow H^1(k,\mathrm{Pic}(\bar{C}))$ is surjective.

$$\begin{array}[c]{ccc}
H^1(k,\mathrm{Pic}^0(\bar{J}))& {\rightarrow}&H^1(k,\mathrm{Pic}(\bar{J}))\\
\downarrow &&\downarrow\\
H^1(k,\mathrm{Pic}^0(\bar{C}))& {\rightarrow}&H^1(k,\mathrm{Pic}(\bar{C}))
\end{array}$$

Now suppose $C$ is projective with one singularity that is a multiple point, then $\mathrm{Pic}^0(\bar{C})$ is an extension of $\mathrm{Pic}^0(\tilde{C})$ by an algebraic group reflecting this singularity of $C$, where $\tilde{C}$ is the normalization of $\bar{C}$. Here $\mathrm{Pic}^0(\bar{C})$ is called the *generalized Jacobian variety*. I believe the algebraic group in this case is $\mathbb{G}_m^{r-1}$, where $r$ is the degree of the multiple point.

**Question 2.** Let $X$ be the smooth affine curve defined by removing the multiple point of $C$. One has an embedding by Serre $X \hookrightarrow \mathrm{Pic}^0(\bar{C}) = :S$ which is analogous to $C \hookrightarrow J$. Do we also have the surjectivity of $H^1(k,\mathrm{Pic}(\bar{S})) \rightarrow H^1(k,\mathrm{Pic}(\bar{X}))$?

**EDIT.** I've change question 2 slightly, because of a misconception explained by the comments below. In this case, we can relax the condition that genus of $C$ is at least 1, since for genus zero it will be trivially true.

Comment: For Q1: yes, $Pic^0(\bar J)= \bar J^\vee = \bar J=Pic^0(\bar C)$ because the last group is the Jacobian, and the Jacobian is self dual.

Comment: @DonuArapura In this case the Jacobian is self dual because $C$ is a curve, am I right? Thanks anyway!

Comment: The Jacobian has a principal polarization, and principally polarized varieties are self dual.

Comment: For Q2: what do you mean by $\mathrm{Pic}^0(\bar{X})$ when $\bar{X}$ is not proper? Same problem with  $\mathrm{Pic}^0(\bar{S})$.

Comment: In any case $\operatorname{Pic}(\mathbb{G}_m) $ is trivial, so the answer to Q2. is certainly no.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly I know $\mathrm{Pic}(\bar{X})$ can be defined, but what is the issue when considering only degree 0 divisor classes to define $\mathrm{Pic}^0(\bar{X})$? Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @abx My bad, I should've assumed that $C$ does not have genus zero, because otherwise the Jacobian is trivial here.

Comment: On a non-proper curve, the degree of a divisor *class* does not make sense.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Thank you, I've never thought of it before. I've edited the question, this was what I really wanted to know.